# Multiple choice Javascript - Looking for a smart way to make it work

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, switch-statement, multiple-choice

I am trying to make a multiplechoice game with all the text inside variables :

For exemple the HTML code is :

```
<p id ="story"></p>

<div id="hide1"><input type="radio" name="sex" id="Button1" class="Button"><p id="choice1">Choice1</p></div>

<div id="hide2"><input type="radio" name="sex" id="Button2" class="Button"><p id="choice2">Choice2</p></div>

<button type="button" id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Continue</button>
```

The Javascript code is :

```
var Choix = [
"TEST1",
"TEST2",
"TEST3",
"TEST4",
"TEST5",
];

document.getElementById("story").innerHTML = Choix[0];

function myFunction()
{
    if (document.getElementById('Button1').checked) 
    {
        document.getElementById("story").innerHTML = Choix[1];
        document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML = "Choice3";
        document.getElementById('choice2').innerHTML = "Choice4";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('Button2').checked) 
    {
        document.getElementById("story").innerHTML = Choix[2];
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('Button3').checked) 
    {
        document.getElementById("story").innerHTML = Choix[3];
    }
}
```

The main issue actually is that my radio buttons are not changing when I display a different Var... it always lead me to the same part of the function. I made a lot of test but the few Ideas I found sound really bad to me (it includes tons of coding) and I am sure there is a smart way to keep it simple. But I can't find one. :/

I would like to keep the button which call a function.

Maybe a switch will be better than an if / else if ?

I am a beginner so I hope my question was clear enough :/

Thank you

Comment: Your code is quite hard to understand, or rather, what exactly you want to happen is unclear from your code. Please explain/annotate the code to say what should happen. Also, where are these 3 checkable buttons?? I see only two!

Comment: Is it possible during your game that you would want more than two radio buttons (choices) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of your question *i think* this is what you had in mind:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Game </title>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var Choix = 
    ["TEST1",   
     "TEST2",   
     "TEST3",   
     "TEST4",   
     "TEST5"];

    window.onload = function()
    {
         document.getElementById("story").innerHTML = Choix[0];
    }

    function myFunction()
    {
        var story = document.getElementById("story").innerHTML;
        var button_1_checked = document.getElementById('Button1').checked;
        var button_2_checked = document.getElementById('Button2').checked;

        if ( story == Choix[0] )
           {
                if ( button_1_checked ) 
                {
                document.getElementById("story").innerHTML = Choix[1];
                document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML = "Choice3";
                document.getElementById('choice2').innerHTML = "Choice4";
                }
                else if ( button_2_checked ) 
                {
                    //do somthing
                }
           }

        if ( story == Choix[1] )
            {
                if ( button_1_checked ) 
                {
                document.getElementById("story").innerHTML = Choix[2];
                }
                else if ( button_2_checked ) 
                {
                document.getElementById("story").innerHTML = Choix[3];
                }
            }

        if ( story == Choix[2] )
            {
                if ( button_1_checked ) 
                {
                    //do somthing
                }
                else if ( button_2_checked ) 
                {
                    //do somthing
                }
            }

        //a set of if statements for each Story / 'TEST'
        //...


        if ( button_1_checked == false && button_2_checked == false)
           {    
               alert("Please make a choice first!");
               return;
           }

        document.getElementById('Button1').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('Button2').checked = false;
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <p id="story"></p>

    <div id="hide1">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="Button1" class="Button">
    <p id="choice1">Choice1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="hide2">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="Button2" class="Button">
    <p id="choice2">Choice2</p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Continue</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its a pleasure! Please dont forget to mark my answer as correct if it works well for you :)

Answer (score 0):

`else if` pattern can be replaced with a alternatives, each of which can decide if it's its case and what code to execute.

```
for (Alternative alternative : alternative) {
  if (alternative.isConditionMet()) return alternative.execute()
}
```

in your case it's something like:

```
alternative[0] = {
  isConditionMet : function() {
     return document.getElementById('Button1').checked
  }
  execute : function() {
     document.getElementById("story").innerHTML = Choix[1];
     document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML = "Choice3";
     document.getElementById('choice2').innerHTML = "Choice4";
  }
}
```

and so on